# How do I add a default constructor to my class

Tags: actionscript-3

The following is my constructor class, however when I try to add the argument when I instantiate my object, I get an error saying I have no default constructor. I basically want to pass a string to the object, but not all objects will get a string.

```
    public function Shortcuts(opencontent:String){
        highlight = new shortcuthighlight();


        highlight.x = highlight.x - highlight.width/2;
        highlight.y = highlight.y - highlight.height/2;
        highlight.visible = false;
        addChild(highlight);
        setChildIndex(highlight,0);

        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, addHighlight);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, removeHighlight);

        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragOn);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragOff);





    }
```

Here is how I create my objects.

```
for(var i=0; i<shortcutsArray.length;i++){
        var className:Class = getDefinitionByName(shortcutsArray[i][0]) as Class;
        var object:Object = new className('hey');
        var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(object);
        mc.x = shortcutsArray[i][1];
        mc.y= shortcutsArray[i][2];
        addChild(mc);


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want `opencontent` to be optional, you can set a default parameter:

```
public function Shortcuts(opencontent:String=null)
{
    /* ... */
}
```